# How to get this condition in where clause of Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which gives me the last month's completed data

```
select * from Tabl
where  datepart(month, completed_date) = DATEPART(month, getDate())-1 
and datepart(year, completed_date) = datepart(year, getDate())
```

But it gives me wrong data when the current date is in january

How can I write the condition to return correct data if the current month is January?

Comment: Change your approach so that your where clause looks for completed_date >= something and completed_date < the day after something else.  It will run faster that way.  As far as getting those variable go, it depends on how you are calling this query.  If it's from application code, it might be easier to use that.  Otherwise, you can use tsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server's DATEADD function will help you here.

```
select * from Tabl
where  datepart(month, completed_date) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(MM,-1,getDate()))
and datepart(year, completed_date) = datepart(year, DATEADD(MM,-1,getDate()))
```

The 'MM' used is just a keyword for Month.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try subtracting one month from the date instead:

```
select *
from Tabl
where month(completed_date) = month(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) and
      year(completed_date) = year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate());
```

But, if you have an index on `completed_date`, it is better to put all the operations on `getdate()` so the expression is "sargable" (that is, an index can be used):

```
where completed_date >= cast(dateadd(month, -1, getdate() - day(getdate() + 1) as date) and
      completed_date < cast(getdate() - day(getdate())
```

When you subtract the "day of the month" from the date, you get the last day of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Tabl
where 
  datepart(year, completed_date) * 100 + datepart(month, completed_date) 
  < 
  datepart(year, getDate()) * 100 + datepart(month, GetDate())
```